# Make sure object is defined before calling function - angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently implementing [anno.JS](http://iamdanfox.github.io/anno.js/) to my project, and I have the following problem: My controller gets the configuration for the object in a variable which is not accessible in the constructor (but e.g. in the `$onInit` function). But I have one problem:

Defining my anno the following

```
this.anno1 = new AnnoModule.Anno(this.annoConfig);
```

works in general, so the definition works, but somehow (when I call `this.anno1.show()` it says `Cannot read property 'show' of undefined`, and when I look in developer tools, i can see that `anno1` is undefined, so I would somehow need to make sure, that the anno is defined, before calling the show function.

Currently I have the definition in the init, so

```
$onInit(){
    this.anno1 = new AnnoModule.Anno(this.annoConfig);
}
```

And then I have the function

```
showAnno(){
    this.anno1.show();
}
```

which is called on a button click.

How can I make sure, the anno is defined?

**EDIT:**
As I said showAnno() is called when clicking a button, now I tried to call the function automatically when page is loaded with a special get-parameter, and it works. Also, in Developer Tools you see, that `this.anno1` has it's values, whereas after the button click it hasn't... The thing that I really don't understand then, is that I just debugged it, and noticed that the anno1 is definetely initialized (if i click the button or not), but when clicking the button, anno1 is undefined again, whereas with the other method its still defined.

**Edit2**: Problem solved. Somehow, I had a problem with the `this` in the function `showAnno()` (which was the wrong one). Now I needed to call `.bind(this)` and now it works.

Comment: Add this to your button: `ng-disabled="!controllerName.anno1"`. This will disable the button until `anno1` has been initialized. (I used `controllerName` because I don't know how you have your controller defined on your view, but it looks like you are using controllerAs syntax based on your use of `this.`)

Comment: @Lex but is there then a difference between waiting a minute until clicking or having it disabled? Because how long I ever wait, it doesn't seem to load..

Comment: Is `$onInit()` even being called? Isn't that function only used in component controllers? Have you written this as a component?

Comment: @Lex its a directive controller, yes. And yes I double checked that the function is called...

Comment: Just to be clear, using the `ng-disabled` method **did not** work. Is that correct? Can you update your question with what you have tried and describe the result?

Comment: @Lex thats correct, I will update it tomorrow.

Comment: That would seem to indicate that `anno1` is never initialized.

Comment: Thought so too, but theres one strange thing: As I said `showAnno()` is called when clicking a button, now I tried to call the function automatically when page is loaded with a special get-parameter, and it works. Also, in Developer Tools you see, that `this.anno1` has it's values, whereas after the button click it hasn't... The thing that I really don't understand then, is that I just debugged it, and noticed that the anno1 is definetely initialized (if i click the button or not), but when clicking the button, anno1 is undefined again, whereas with the other method its still defined

Comment: see 2nd Edit - problem solved

Answer (score 0):

```
if(this.anno1 != null){
this.anno1.show();
}
```

but what do you want it to do if it is null? Wait?

Comment: I had the same idea already as well, but what I'm wondering about is, that whenever I click the button (that triggers the `showAnno()-function`, it's still not defined...

Comment: If it were me I would deactivate the button until it is defined. Once it is done being defined then activate the button.

Comment: That wouldn't be so easy, as there are 4 files, where this has to do with each other...  Is there maybe a function in angular, where I could make sure, that nothing else is executed, until the object is defined.

Comment: function checkAnnoDefined(an){
 if(an==null) {
        setTimeout(function(){ checkAnnoDefined(); }, 500);
        return false;
    } else {
        //Defined At This Point
    }
}

Comment: You may be able to use something like that. Im not sure exactly what you are trying to do but that might work.